# Periodically running function on all running threads from `LD_PRELOAD` library

Tags: c++, c, pthreads

I am working on an `LD_PRELOAD` Unix tool that requires periodically pausing and inspecting all running threads with little overhead.

I already have a working version for single-threaded applications, leveraging signals and static initialization.

```cpp
extern "C" void handler(int) {
    // ...
}

struct Initialization {
    Initialization() {
        signal(SIGALRM, handler);
        struct itimerval timer;
        timer.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
        timer.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
        timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
        timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
        setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timer, nullptr);
    }
};

static Initialization _;
```

Two problems come up when it comes to supporting multi-threaded applications.

1. Signals are only delivered to a single thread.
2. `thread_local` initilization [does not seem to happen like I want it to here](https://godbolt.org/z/1e74ezdMP).

Is there any way I can make this work? I was thinking of using `pthread_kill` to forward the timer signal to all threads, but in this case I would still need to find the ID of all running threads. This is where `thread_local` static initialization would help so I could use `pthread_self`. I would like to avoid interposing on `pthread_create` unless no other option seems simpler.

Comment: I'm genuinely curious as to what kind of things are happening in that `handler`. Given the severe restrictions of signal handlers, and the described mission statement, it'll be quite an effort to accomplish it without undefined behavior, so the whole thing would be a moot point.

Comment: I'm keeping some `malloc` related statistics, and periodically need to call `malloc` as if coming from the original thread. It just occurred to me that since I am already interposing `malloc` and it is called with relatively high frequency from each thread, I could also use a countdown there.

Comment: More specifically: you must limit yourself to the functions in [man 7 signal-safety](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). Notably absent: print formatting, memory allocations, file io except the raw open/read/write.

Comment: You cannot call `malloc` from a signal handler. Forget the whole thing. It's not going to work.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll forget about signal handlers completely. I think the solution here is to do more in the `malloc` interposition.

Comment: Sadly, `setitimer` [is obsolescent](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setitimer.html#tag_16_202_07).  You may wish to consider [`timer_settime`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/timer_settime.html), instead, if you return to your signal-based implementation.